# can't uncompress a gzip compressed data

Tags: compression, gzip

I have extracted a file 'linux' from ubutu installation .iso file.
The command `file linux` gives me this output.

> linux: gzip compressed data, was
> "vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic.efi.signed", last modified: Sat Jul 11
> 08:53:21 2020, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32
> 30118272

To uncompress it, I tried `gzip -d linux` but it gives me `gzip: linux: unknown suffix -- ignored` as output.  How can I extract or uncompress this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gunzip` (or `gzip -d`) tries to infer the output filename by removing the "dot suffix" from the input file name. Since filename `linux` doesn't have a suffix, if doesn't know what to name the output.

If your version of `gzip` supports the `-N` option you can try using that to restore the extracted file's original name:

```
   -N --name
          When  compressing,  always  save the original file name and time
          stamp; this is the  default.  When  decompressing,  restore  the
          original  file  name  and  time stamp if present. This option is
          useful on systems which have a limit on file name length or when
          the time stamp has been lost after a file transfer.
```

Otherwise probably the simplest thing is to rename the input file (to `linux.gz` for example). Alternatively, decompress to standard output and redirect to a filename of your choosing: `gzip -dc linux > vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic.efi.signed`

Comment: Thanks! (I feel like I was a headless dude back then :) )